# How to use CKEditor plugin in Outsystems?

Tags: ckeditor, outsystems

I need to use CKEditor in one of my applications. I have used CKEditor plugin in outsystems. but not working.. can anyone tell how to install the ckeditor on the outsystems web.

Comment: If you're referring to the CKEditor Forge component, you might have better luck posting to the support page of the component (https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component-discussions/97/CKEditor).

Also, if you want help, you may want to consider providing more information than just "not working". As in, are you seeing error messages?

Answer (score 1):

For OutSystems-related questions I'd advise you to go over to the [OutSystems forums](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/). You'll get an answer a lot quicker there! (Also, you need to provide more information, "not working" is really too little to go by in order to get help!)

Answer (score -1):

You you install the ckeditor you have a espace template to explain how it works